# Selecting multiple MIN columns and other data from same table

Tags: mysql

Evening. Hope someone can help. Been stumped with this for a few days now...

I have the following table....

```
| ID | Supplier | Item_1 | Cost_1 | Item_2 | Cost_2 | Item_3 | Cost_3 |
+----+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |        1 |   732w |   3.99 |   314d |   7.58 |   399p |  15.44 |
|  1 |        2 | SyYh33 |   3.78 | GjuUh4 |   7.60 | 2su7js |  15.45 |
|  1 |        3 |   5443 |   4.01 |   9833 |   7.63 |   7433 |  15.22 |
|  2 |        1 |   596q |  15.42 |   933k |  28.56 |   732c |  69.99 |
|  2 |        2 | hyjs9k |  15.86 | ka7snf |  28.99 | h23nfs |  68.99 |
|  2 |        3 |   5477 |  14.99 |   5658 |  28.49 |   8153 |  70.15 |
+----+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now what i would like to do is return the cheapest price from columns Cost_1, Cost_2, Cost_3 with it's corresponding Item column and Supplier for each ID....

So basically would like the following result

```
| ID | Supplier_1 | Item_1 | Cost_1 | Supplier_2 | Item_2 | Cost_2 | Supplier_3 | Item_3 | Cost_3 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |          2 | SyYh33 |   3.78 |          1 |   314d |   7.58 |          3 |   7433 |  15.22 |
|  2 |          3 |   5477 |  14.99 |          3 |   5658 |  28.49 |          2 | h23nfs |  68.99 |
```

Any pointers would be great. Tried with joins and MIN() but i haven't been able to return the desired results. Hopefully there is a MySQL guru out there that can put me out of my misery. Thanks in advance

Comment: The schema of the original table makes this problem very hard to solve (if possible at all). Are you allowed to pivot the table? Ideally, you want columns `ID,Supplier,Item,Cost` (with three rows of items for each combination of ID and Supplier).

Comment: I think you may be discovering why normalized tables are considered helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize your schema - Otherwise you will have to live with queries like this:

```
select f.ID,
    i1.Supplier as Supplier_1,
    i1.Item_1,
    i1.Cost_1,
    i2.Supplier as Supplier_2,
    i2.Item_2,
    i2.Cost_2,
    i3.Supplier as Supplier_3,
    i3.Item_3,
    i3.Cost_3
from (select distinct ID from following_table) f
join following_table i1 on i1.ID = f.ID and i1.Supplier = (
    select t.Supplier
    from following_table t
    where t.ID = i1.ID
    order by Cost_1 asc
    limit 1
)
join following_table i2 on i2.ID = f.ID and i2.Supplier = (
    select t.Supplier
    from following_table t
    where t.ID = i2.ID
    order by Cost_2 asc
    limit 1
)
join following_table i3 on i3.ID = f.ID and i3.Supplier = (
    select t.Supplier
    from following_table t
    where t.ID = i3.ID
    order by Cost_3 asc
    limit 1
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04933/2

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to combine your results.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Cost_1 = (SELECT MIN(Cost_1) FROM your_table)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Cost_2 = (SELECT MIN(Cost_2) FROM your_table)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Cost_3 = (SELECT MIN(Cost_3) FROM your_table)
```

Comment: is it giving supplier_1 col as well?